# Ebay Webscraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to select just the sale price for each item listed but this is the closest I can get.

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url =  'http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=graphics%20card&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&rt=nc&_trksid=p2045573.m1684'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
Sale_Price = [tag['class'] for tag in soup.find_all("span", class_="bold bidsold")]
print(Sale_Price)
```

which gives me:
    [['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 
'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold'], ['bold', 'bidsold']]

Comment: What's confusing about that? You selected the class that you searched for... Try putting something other than `tag['class']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing the name of the `class`. The price is in the `string`. Use `get_text()` to get the `string`. The strings include a lot of spaces or new line, use `strip()` to get rid of these.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=graphics%20card&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&rt=nc&_trksid=p2045573.m1684'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
Sale_Price =[ tag.get_text().strip() for tag in soup.find_all("span", class_="bold bidsold") ]
print(Sale_Price)
```

It gives the output:

```
['£159.99', '£240.00', '£8.00', '£100.00', '£54.99', '£324.99', '£10.00', '£130.00', '£21.00', '£68.00', '£25.00', '£90.00', '£210.00', '£269.49', '£90.56', '£5.90', '£56.00', '£89.99', '£142.00', '£104.00', '£35.00', '£8.80', '£27.00', '£45.00', '£45.00', '£115.11', '£293.19', '£172.00', '£42.00', '£14.39', '£120.00', '£24.99', '£11.73', '£10.50', '£88.00', '£340.00', '£136.82', '£5.00', '£21.32', '£66.46', '£49.99', '£25.00', '£30.00', '£385.00', '£258.00', '£64.30', '£87.00', '£29.99', '£77.99', '£36.88', '£71.00']
```

**EDIT** 
If you want to ignore `£` sign then take the string without first character.

```
Sale_Price =[ tag.get_text().strip()[1:] for tag in soup.find_all("span", class_="bold bidsold") ]
print(Sale_Price)
```

This will store only the prices without `£` sign.

Comment: Thank you very much. Any idea how to then remove the £ sign from each string? I'm a beginner and not to familiar with regex but from my googling I've gathered `re.sub('[£]', '', line) ]` is involved somehow...

Comment: @JoshDiamond No need of `regex`. I've updated the code, take a look.

Comment: @JoshDiamond you still have any problem ?

Comment: @JoshDiamond Just a suggestion, if the ans solves your problem you should accept it. So, others can find useful answers for similar problem and people know that you problem is solved.

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of a noob :p

Comment: Nothing to be sorry. It's ok. :)